# Cassandra select rows ordered by added date

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra

I try to store emails for newsletter mailing app in Cassandra.

Current schema is :

```
CREATE TABLE emails (
    email varchar,
    comment varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (email));
```

I don't know how to get emails ordered by added time(so emails can be processed in parallel on different nodes).

Answer (score 1):

PlayOrm on cassandra can do that sort of stuff under the covers for you as long as you are able to partition your data so you can still scale.  You can query into your partitions.  The order by is not yet there but a trick is instead to use where time > 0 to get everything after 1970 epoch which forces it to use the time index and then just traverse the cursor backwards for reverse order(or forwards for sorted order).

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra orders on write based on your column comparator.  You can't order results using any arbitrary column in your predicate.  If you want to retrieve in time order, you must insert with your timestamp as your column name (or the first element in a composite name).  You can also create a second CF that would store time-ordered records that you can query if needed. Unfortunately CQL gives the illusion of RDBMS-like query capability, when in reality it's still a column store with the associated query capabilities.  My suggestion is to either avoid CQL (and use Thrift-based queries instead) or make sure you understand what it's doing under the covers.